# Generic function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function with generic type in typescript. I have these  function  whose do the same

```
const convertBeverages = (beveragesCollection: BeveragesQuery): Beverage[] => {
    let beverages: Beverage[] = [];

    if (beveragesCollection) {
        beverages =
            beveragesCollection.data.map(({ id, attributes }) => {
                const restaurant =
                    attributes?.restaurant?.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
                        const restaurantId = currentValue?.restaurant?.data?.id ?? "-1";

                        return currentValue && currentValue.available
                            ? [...acc, { price: currentValue.price, restaurantId }]
                            : acc;
                    }, [] as PriceRestaurant[]) ?? [];

                const beverage = {
                    id: id ?? "",
                    name: attributes?.name ?? "",
                    position: attributes?.position ?? 0,
                    restaurant,
                };

                return beverage;
            }) ?? [];
    }
    return beverages;
};
```

```
const convertDesserts = (dessertCollection: DessertsQuery): Dessert[] => {
    let desserts: Dessert[] = [];

    if (dessertCollection) {
        desserts =
            dessertCollection.data.map(({ id, attributes }) => {
                const restaurant =
                    attributes?.restaurant?.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
                        const restaurantId = currentValue?.restaurant?.data?.id ?? "-1";

                        return currentValue && currentValue.available
                            ? [...acc, { price: currentValue.price, restaurantId }]
                            : acc;
                    }, [] as PriceRestaurant[]) ?? [];

                const dessert: Dessert = {
                    id: id ?? "",
                    name: attributes?.name ?? "",
                    position: attributes?.position ?? 0,
                    restaurant,
                };

                return dessert;
            }) ?? [];
    }

    return desserts;
};
```

So i want to create a generic function but i have an error and i don't know why.
Basically , i copied the previous function and I added the `TData` with the input for the previous functions and the `TModel` for the value of return

[image: typescript error]

Comment: Please edit your question to replace image with actual code and error message.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, replace `TData = BeveragesQuery | DessertsQuery` with `TData extends BeveragesQuery | DessertsQuery`. Using the equals sign you just give the default value to the parameter, but don't constrain it in any way, so one could call a function with `convertSimpleModel<number, ...>` for example and it would make no sense to access property `.data` on `number`.

Secondly, you don't need the `TModel` parameter, if you leave it, I could call `convertSimpleModel<BeveragesQuery, Dessert>` and the function would be supposed to convert beverages to desserts which doesn't make sense either. Or even worse something like `convertSimpleModel<DessertsQuery, number & string>`. Instead use conditional type `BeveragesQuery extends TData ? Beverage : Dessert` where you would put `TModel` otherwise. So

```
function convertSimpleModel<TData extends BeveragesQuery | DessertsQuery>(
  collection: TData
): BeveragesQuery extends TData ? Beverage[] : Dessert[] {...}
```

Notice, that this is still not perfect, for example I could call `convertSimpleModel<BeveragesQuery | DessertsQuery>(...)` which will definitely lead to weird results. Also you probably won't be able to type the array `modelElements` correctly without using type assertions. Maybe what you want is not generics, but function overloads

```
function convertSimpleModel(collection: BeveragesQuery): Beverage[]
function convertSimpleModel(collection: DessertsQuery): Dessert[]
function convertSimpleModel(collection: BeveragesQuery | DessertsQuery): (Beverage | Dessert)[] {
  const modelElements: (Beverage | Dessert)[] = []
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
I'm a little confused because with the instruction `TData =  BeveragesQuery | DessertsQuery`  i thought the `TData` values can be one type or another, constraint the type. I thought  `extend` was  used for interfaces, not for constraint the types

And yep, for my use case I think is better overload the function signature

Comment: No, `TData = ` doesn't constrain types, it only provides the default value for the cases when typescript cannot infer anything better. `extends` is used to constrain it. Please read the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of generics

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you fix the issue:

```
// A simplified example

type A = {
    data: string
}

type B = {
    data: number
}


function test1<TData extends A | B>(collection: TData) {
    // compiles
    console.log(collection.data) // type is 'number | string'
}
```

What you're trying to do is add a constraint to your generic type.

The `extends` keyword is how you add generic constraints (See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

TL:DR: Replace the `=` with `extends`.